# Multiple DKIM per domain

Tags: email, dkim

I have one DKIM key that I use with Google Apps. Which under the DNS TXT Record is `v=DKIM1;`

Now I am adding a second DKIM authentication for PHP mail.
With this second key, do I make it `v=DKIM2;`, or do I leave it as `1`?

Comment: doesn't matter. php doesn't deliver/send mail. it just walks your envelope down to the street corner and drops it into the mailbox (smtp server). php has nothing to do with dkim, nor should it.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-add-multiple-DKIM-records-in-my-DNS-without-any-possible-downsides says that  "As for multiple records, no problem; just give them different selector names."

Comment: @SubinThomas Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v=DKIM1 must remain '1' as it represents the DKIM version, not the order of records.

Answer (score 1):

not the record content but key selector that is used as subdomain must be different and matching actual key used by mailing part/software like: key1._domainkey.yourdomain.com, key2._domainkey.yourdomain.com etc.